# Problem with AndroidManifest.xml file in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to Android development, and I am trying to get familiar with it with some tutorials. Currently, I am stuck with this so could you please guide me through this? I have an issue with my AndroidManifest.xml file when I try to run it in debug. I added the trace of the error below along with the xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ebook"
    android:versionCode="1000"
          android:versionName="1.0.0">
   

   <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
        
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    

    
</manifest>

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
       > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
          > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Alberto/OneDrive/Escritorio/flutter_ebook/ebook/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 44; El atributo "name" enlazado al espacio de nombres "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ya se ha especificado para el elemento "application".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is you added duplication line

```
        android:name="${applicationName}" (A)
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"(B)
```

if you want your app support multidex - Keep A, let yourApplication class extend MultiDexApplication - then remove (B)

Answer (score 0):

You have the same attribute two times:

```
   <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

I suppose you want to create multidex application (to overcome 64K methods limit), so you should remove `android:name="${applicationName}"`. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.